# Replacing an element by sliding it out and a new one in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

basically, I want to show a table, and when the user clicks a link, I want the table to slide out to the left and another table to slide in from the right to the position where the original table was.

I've come so far (http://jsfiddle.net/JqkyA/4/):

```
$( "table.grid-1" ).hide( "slide", { direction: "left", duration: 5000 } );
$( "table.grid-2" ).show( "slide", { direction: "right", duration: 5000 });
```

Problem is, while the second table is sliding in, its x-position is correct but it is always displayed below the original table. I don't want that - I want the second table to slide in at the exact same y-position as the original table.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

To be clear, I would like the new table to slide in on the same y-coordinate as the old table, but I still want the old table to be shown during slide-out. I also would like to have the new table slide in right next to the old one (no 'pause' between the tables as wm.p1us suggested).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should go with a different approach.
Instead of sliding the 2 tables just slide their container using negative margin and then hide the first table using the complete callback.

I also added `display: inline-block` to both tables.

**Something like this:**

```
$(".grids").animate({'margin-left': -110 }, 5000, function () {
     $('table.grid-1').hide();
     $(this).css("margin-left", 0);
});
```

**[See this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JqkyA/6/)**

Comment: hm, not a bad idea actually

Comment: I've switched to this approach now, as it seems to be the cleanest to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( function() {
$( "a" ).click( function() {
            $( "table.grid-1" ).css({'position': 'absolute'});
    $( "table.grid-1" ).hide( "slide", { direction: "left", duration: 5000 });

    $( "table.grid-2" ).show( "slide", { direction: "right", duration: 5000 });
    } );
 } );
```

Comment: Tried this as well, however, my actual table is a lot wider, and it would be better if there was no 'pause' between sliding the old table out and the new one in. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: oh, nice one, and I like it because I don't have to modify my css.

Answer (score 1):

I've forked your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQ5mj/)

I added

```
<div class="inner">
```

as an inner wrapper and floated the tables to the left. animation is done by changing `margin-left` of the first table.

This will work as you wanted - the first table is still visible when the second one comes in..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$( function() {
    $( "a" ).click( function() {

        if($( "table.grid-1" ).css('display') != 'none')
        {
            $( "table.grid-1" ).hide();
        }  
        $( "table.grid-2" ).show( "slide", { direction: "right", duration: 5000 });
    } );
} );
```

Let me know is it usefull?.

Comment: I've tried this approach already, problem here is, that I still want the original table to show during slide-out.